# problemas con ajax y php y mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

tengo un listado con un checkbox, y a partir del checkbox, cuando = checked debe grabar en la bdatos y si lo desactivamos pues vuelve a grabar en la bdatos (campo preliquidar = 0/1. El problema es que la idea la tengo clara pero no consigo que funcione ni Debuguear.
Adjunto código para ver si me podéis ayudar. GRACIAS

[image: La idea es que cada vez que haga click en el Checkbox, guarde el estado del mismo en al bdatos]

`````
````
    <?php 
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION["idSession"])) {
        header("Location: logout.php");
    }
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
    include_once("../admin/dbconect.php");

    $database = new Connection();
    $db = $database->open();


if($_GET['zona'] <> '' or $_GET['zona'] <> NULL){
    $activado = $_GET['zona'];
}else{
    $activado = '';
}
if($_GET['proveedor'] <> '' OR $_GET['proveedor'] <> NULL){
    $proveedor = $_GET['proveedor'];
}

$sqlZona = "SELECT * FROM registros WHERE ELIMINADA = 0 AND ZONA like '".$activado."%' AND FECHA_HORA > '2020-07-01 00:00:01'";

$dbIncidencia = $db->query($sqlZona);


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Proveedores</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php include_once ('./navbar.php') ?>
  <div id="resultado"></div>
  <div class="cuerpo">
      <H1 align="center"><?php echo $_GET['proveedor']; ?></H1>
      <H3 align="center"><?php echo $_GET['zona'] ?></H3>
      <table border="1px solid black">
          <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>POBLACIÓN</th>
              <th>CÓDIGO POSTAL</th>
              <th>TELÉFONO FIJO</th>
              <th>TELÉFONO MÓVIL</th>
              <th>FECHA INCIDENCIA</th>
              <th>APARATO</th>
              <th>IMPORTE</th>
              <th>LIQUIDAR</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <?php
                  foreach ($dbIncidencia as $zona){
                    echo "<td>".$zona['ID']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$zona['POBLACION']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$zona['CP']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$zona['TELEFONO_1']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$zona['TELEFONO_2']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$zona['FECHA_HORA']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$zona['APARATO']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".precio($zona['ZONA'],$zona['APARATO'])."</td>";
                    if($zona['LIQUIDARPROVEEDOR'] == 1){ $num = 'checked'; } else {$num = '';};
                    echo "<td><input id=".$zona['ID']." name='liquidar[]' type='checkbox' ".$num." onchange='preliquidar(this,".$zona['ID'].")'></td></tr>";
                    //echo "<td><input name='liquidar[]' type='checkbox' value=1 onclick='grabarDatos(".$zona['ID'].")'></td></tr>";
                  }
              ?>
          </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
function precio($zona,$aparato){
    $zona = substr($zona,0,3);
    include_once('../admin/dbconect.php');
    $database = new Connection();
    $db = $database->open();
    $sqlMenu = "SELECT * FROM proveedores WHERE ELIMINADA = 0 AND zona = '".trim($zona)."' AND aparato = '".$aparato."'";
    $dbmenu = $db->query($sqlMenu);
    foreach ($dbmenu as $opmenu) {
        $listMenu = $opmenu['precio'];
    }
    return $listMenu;
}

?>
<script>
    function preliquidar(activado, id){
        var preliquidada = activado;
        var incidencia = id;
        if(activado.checked){
            incidencia = id;
            preliquidada = 1;
        }else{
            incidencia = id;
            preliquidada = 0;
        }
        var parametros = {
                "preliquidada" : preliquidada,
                "incidencia" : incidencia
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "./preliquidarProveedores.php",
            method: 'POST',
            data: parametros,
            success: function(data){
                $('#resultado').html(data);
            }
        });

    }


</script>

´´´
  
y el fichero que recoje el POST de insertar a mysql nombre fichero: preliquidarProveedores.php

````
<?php
$database = new Connection();
$db = $database->open();
if(isset($_POST['preliquidada'])){
    $incidencia = $_POST['incidencia'];
    $preliquidada = $_POST['preliquidada'];
    $sqlPrel = "UPDATE registros SET LIQUIDARPROVEEDOR = $preliquidada WHERE ID = $incidencia";
    var_dump($sqlPrel);
    $insertar = $db->query($sqlPrel);
    $insertar->execute();
    $database->close();
}
?>
´´´
`````

El problema que le veo es que no me llega lo datos a la consulta mysql. Otra cosa que no se como hacer, es hacer debug del ajax. Supongo que sí se puede pero no se como hacerlo, utilizo PHPStorm.

gracias otra vez

Comment: Si tienes un listado y a todos los checkbox les asignas mismo ID no va a funcionar, los ID deben ser únicos; también necesitas saber qué registro es el que se va a modificar, pero tienes que mostrar más código para poder sugerir algo, al menos una fila completa, no solo el checkbox.

Comment: En el listado ahora cada uno tiene un ID diferente, nunca será repetido, pero aún así soy incapaz de pasarlo.

Comment: Ojo con tu función `precio()`, estás creando una nueva conexión PHP cada vez y es posible que comiences a recibir errores conforme se incrementen las consultas. Considera crear un método donde `$db` esté disponible o pasarla como parámetro; en el peor de los casos, usa `global $db;` para acceder a la que ya tienes en lugar de crear una nueva.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con _pero aún así soy incapaz de pasarlo_? Al inicio de tu PHP haz un `var_dump($_POST);` para ver lo que estás recibiendo y agrégalo a la pregunta.

Comment: OK para la $db. Aunque ahora el problema que tengo es, 
Quiero que cada vez que cambie el checkbox me guarde el check en la base de datos o al desmarcarlo me borre el valor de la db. Tengo claro que es usar Ajax con POST, pero no consigo que me funcione. En los campos incidencia da el id de la incidencia y en preliquidada es 1 o 0 según esté activado o no el checkbox.

Comment: Triby. No me muestra nada. es por eso que no se como reproducirlo, y en Chrome debugando no me da error por ningún lado...

Comment: Antes de ejecutar la petición AJAX agrega `console.log(parametros);` y revisa la consola para ver si están los datos como los necesitas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110740/discussion-between-noe-moreno-and-triby).

Comment: Triby, me sale este error yno  me sale el console log
Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at preliquidar (index.php?zona=AV GIRONA&proveedor=TECO:143)
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (index.php?zona=AV GIRONA&proveedor=TECO:122

Comment: Triby, eres un fenómeno!!! Me funciona todo bien. El problema estaba en la versión del JQUERY... Tenía la versión slim minified, he puesto la normal y funciona todo correcto. GRACIAS